# how to center div with html and css only

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

How can I center my webpage only with html & css? I tried it with margin: auto, margin: 0 auto and also margin-left: auto & margin-right: auto. Nothing seems to work from the things I've read on the internet. I'll show you my code. I want that everything is centered. Every Div. And compatible with mobile Applications.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: -220px;
  bottom: -70px;
}

.social #spotifylogo {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -7px;
}

.social #fblogo {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: -1px;
}

.social #twitterlogo {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 6px;
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  right: -495px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: greenyellow;
}

#headpic {
  position: relative;
  right: -225px;
  bottom: -100px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">cyberpVnk</h1>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#headpic">Start</a>
  <a href="#Musik">Musik-Player</a>
  <a href="#Video">Video-Player</a>
  <a href="#Bio">Biografie</a>
  <a href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
</div>
<div class="social">
  <a href="http://www.instagram.com/cyberpvnk9x" target="_blank"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/87/87390.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
  <a href="spotify"><img src="spotify.png" width="40" height="40" id="spotifylogo"></a>
  <a href="facebook"><img src="fbbutton.png" width="26" height="26" id="fblogo"></a>
  <a href="twitter"><img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/84-842524_twitter-logo-in-circular-black-button-twitter-logo.png" width="27" height="27" id="twitterlogo"></a>

</div>
<div id="headpic">
  <img src="headpic.jpg" width="900" height="500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want center items you can use 'flex-box'
something like this

html

```
    <div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item">…</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

for this to work just warp the items with flex box (display: flex) you just put it on your title (h1)
this code is from this article :
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

also there is much more you can do with flex box

can also read abut flex box at w3s
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

I made several tweaks but mainly removed all the flexbox information - this was the biggest change across the CSS edits. Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: greenyellow;
}

#headpic {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#headpic-image {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">cyberpVnk</h1>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#headpic">Start</a>
  <a href="#Musik">Musik-Player</a>
  <a href="#Video">Video-Player</a>
  <a href="#Bio">Biografie</a>
  <a href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
</div>
<div class="social">
  <a href="http://www.instagram.com/cyberpvnk9x" target="_blank"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/87/87390.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
  <a href="spotify"><img src="spotify.png" width="40" height="40" id="spotifylogo"></a>
  <a href="facebook"><img src="fbbutton.png" width="26" height="26" id="fblogo"></a>
  <a href="twitter"><img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/84-842524_twitter-logo-in-circular-black-button-twitter-logo.png" width="27" height="27" id="twitterlogo"></a>

</div>
<div id="headpic">
  <img id="headpic-image" src="headpic.jpg" width="900" height="500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use properties such as top,bottom,left,right to align items unless necessary. It's impossible to get a sensible layout in this way. You do not need to use position: "relative" for each item. A lot of your codes are wrong. I took these parts to comment lines for you to see. You can use flexbox for some structures to center items. Often marginx "auto" will work for inline-block or block-sized elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  /* margin-top: 50px; */
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.social {
  /* float: left; */
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: relative;
            right: -220px;
            bottom: -70px; */
}

.social #spotifylogo {
  /* position: relative;
            bottom: -7px; */
}

.social #fblogo {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* bottom: 1px;
            left: -1px; */
}

.social #twitterlogo {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* bottom: 1px;
            left: 6px; */
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* float: left;
            position: relative;
            right: -495px;
            margin-top: 25px; */
}

.nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: greenyellow;
}

#headpic {
  text-align: center;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* right: -225px;
            bottom: -100px; */
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">cyberpVnk</h1>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#headpic">Start</a>
  <a href="#Musik">Musik-Player</a>
  <a href="#Video">Video-Player</a>
  <a href="#Bio">Biografie</a>
  <a href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
</div>
<div class="social">
  <a href="http://www.instagram.com/cyberpvnk9x" target="_blank"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/87/87390.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
  <a href="spotify"><img src="spotify.png" width="40" height="40" id="spotifylogo"></a>
  <a href="facebook"><img src="fbbutton.png" width="26" height="26" id="fblogo"></a>
  <a href="twitter"><img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/84-842524_twitter-logo-in-circular-black-button-twitter-logo.png" width="27" height="27" id="twitterlogo"></a>

</div>
<div id="headpic">
  <img src="headpic.jpg" width="900" height="500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**add this in your CSS**

```
 div_id(div that you want to change) {
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: margin: 0 auto; centers the selected element